# jquery validation doesn't respond

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

```
<form class="admission" name="form" method="POST" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="new_student">
                  <h2> Student Details </h2>
                    <p>Fields marked with <span class="necessary-field">*</span> must be filled.</p>

                    <label>Admission number
                    <span class="small">Add your name</span>
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" name="Admission_number" id="Admission_number"/><br/>

                    <label>Admission Date
                    <span class="small">Add your name</span>
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" name="Admission_Date" id="Admission_Date" /><br/>

                    <h2>Personal Details</h2><p></p>

                    <label>First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" /><br/>

                    <label>Middle Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="middle_name" id="middle_name" /><br/>

                    <label>Last Name 
                    <span class="small">Last name or Surname</span>
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" /><br/>

                    <label>Course </label>
                    <select id="student_batch_id" name="student_batch_id">
                            <option value="11">10 - 2010 A</option>
                            <option value="14">LKG</option>
                    </select><br/>

                    <label>Date of Birth</label>
                    <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob"/><br/>

                    <label>Gender</label>
                    <select id="gender" name="gender">
                        <option value="Male">Male</option>
                        <option value="Female">Female</option>
                    </select>

                    <label>Blood Group</label>
                    <select id="student_blood_group" name="student_blood_group"><option value="">Unknown</option>
                                      <option value="A+">A+</option>
                                      <option value="A-">A-</option>
                                      <option value="B+">B+</option>
                                      <option value="B-">B-</option>
                                      <option value="O+">O+</option>
                                      <option value="O-">O-</option>
                                      <option value="AB+">AB+</option>
                                      <option value="AB-">AB-</option></select>
                    <label>Identification Marks</label>
                    <input type="text" name="id_mark_1" id="id_mark_1" /><br/>
                    <label>&nbsp;</label>
                    <input type="text" name="id_mark_2" id="id_mark_2" /><br/>

                    <label>Place of Birth</label>
                    <input type="text" name="birth_palace" id="birth_palace" /><br/>

                    <label>Nationality</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nationalaity" id="nationalaity" /><br/>

                    <label>Mother Tongue</label>
                    <input type="text" name="mother_tongue" id="mother_tongue" /><br/>


                    <label>Religion</label>
                    <input type="text" name="religion" id="religion" /><br/>


                    <label>Cast</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cast" id="cast" /><br/>

                    <label>Creed</label>
                    <input type="text" name="creed" id="creed" /><br/>



                    <label>category</label>
                    <select id="student_category_id" name="category_id]">
                                        <option value="">Select a Category</option>
                                      <option value="1">GENERAL</option>
                                      <option value="2">SC/ST</option>
                                      <option value="3">OBC</option>
                                      <option value="4">OEC</option>
                                      <option value="5">NRI</option>
                    </select><br/>

                    <h2>Contact Details</h2><p></p>

                    <label>Address Line1</label>
                    <input type="text" name="address_line1" id="address_line1" /><br/>

                    <label>Address Line2</label>
                    <input type="text" name="address_line2" id="address_line2" /><br/>

                     <label>Locality</label>
                    <input type="text" name="locality" id="locality" /><br/>

                     <label>City</label>
                    <input type="text" name="city" id="city" /><br/>

                    <label>State</label>
                    <input type="text" name="state" id="state" /><br/>

                    <label>PIN</label>
                    <input type="text" name="pin_num" id="pin_num" /><br/>

                    <label>Telephone</label>
                    <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" /><br/>

                     <label>Mobile</label>
                    <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" /><br/>
                    <label>Upload User Photo</label>
                     <span class="small">Upload User Photo (60KB max)</span>
                     <input id="student_photo" name="student_photo" type="file" >
                    <input type="submit" value="NEXT">

                                                      &nbsp;<br/>&nbsp;                    
                  </form>​
```

This form is to be validated. I include these below js files to the page.

```
  <script src="../JavaScript/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="../JavaScript/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And add the java script code:-

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#new_student").validate({
   rules: {
   Admission_number: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 2
 },

Admission_Date: "required"
 },
 messages: {
  Admission_Date: "This is a comment form. Why in the heck would you leave the comment  blank?",

    Admission_number: {
    required: "Stand up for your comments or go home.",
    minlength: jQuery.format("You need to use at least {0} characters for your name.")
}
}

});
});

 </script>
```

I am new to jquery but. I couldnt understand where the mistake is

here is the jsFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/abelkbil/cVjez/

Comment: It would be helpful for you to include the validation script in the fiddle... otherwise it's no point in using jsfiddle. Also why such an ***old*** version of jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me...

http://jsfiddle.net/cVjez/10/

All I did was change the jQuery version to 1.7.2 and then added the [jQuery.validation.js file from the Microsoft Ajax CDN](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/CDNjQueryValidate19.ashx)

Maybe double check that the jquery and jquery validation js libraries are being loaded... the relative path might be wrong or something along those lines.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I am using php, so can in add validation.js from mS CDN?. Once again thanks

Comment: Thanks @charlino I am using php. Can i use MS CDN validation.js ?

Comment: You can use the MS CDN if you want but I would suggest only using it when the site is live and released. When you are developing, use a local copy so you can work off line and it will make debugging easier.

Comment: i copyed the validate.js of MS CDN but fails in validation in localhost. But when i altered in jsFiddle it works fine.